# How to run windows autostart programs depending on conditions

Tags: windows, boot, autostart

I'm looking for a solution to problem of starting programs on windows login (start) depending on condition.

What I wan't to do:

I have a laptop that I use in work and in home.

When I start my laptop at work: I wan't it to start outlook, lync etc...

When I am in home: I don't wan't it to start enything...

It can be time based, wifi network based, network share based...

Looking forward for Your ideas

Comment: The simple solution would be to use different user profiles.

Comment: Well that is a solution ,but it impacts things like firefox, skype documents etc... I don't like that:)

Comment: Run a batch file that attempts to locate a batch file on a network drive.  If the file does not exist do nothing otherwise run the batch file which starts the applications you want open at work.  You can use the built-in tools within Windows to run the batch file.

Comment: Go ahead and post it as an answer (if the system will allow you).

Answer (score 5):

After comments from Ramhound I have created a script and added it to autostart.

```
@echo off
ECHO Waiting a while for a network connection...
timeout /t 7
ping -n 1 -w 25  hostReachableFromOfficeOnly | find "Reply" > nul
if errorlevel 1 goto :HOME
goto :OFFICE

:OFFICE
ECHO Office

start /d"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Lync" communicator.exe
start /d"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Atlassian\SourceTree\" SourceTree.exe
start /d"C:\work\IDE\eclipse-jee-juno-SR2-win32-x86_64\" eclipse.exe
start  /d"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft\ Office\Office14" OUTLOOK.EXE

goto :END

:HOME
ECHO Home!

:END
```

Thank You for all responses.